# Rails - ActiveRecord get database name from an Instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have a model distributed into many databases. Here is an example:

```
class Timetablerange < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "TimetableRange"

  def self.integration(integration)
    self.establish_connection(integration.to_sym)
    return self
  end

end
```

So when I want to fetch an instance from one database:

```
Timetablerange.integration(:integration_id).find(1)
```

I need to get the database_name from an instance without using:

```
Timetable.connection.current_database
```

Since it can be different if I use this:

```
instance_a = Timetablerange.integration(:integration_1).find(1)
instance_b = Timetablerange.integration(:integration_2).find(1)
```

At this time Timetable.connection.current_database = :integration_2 but instance_a was loaded from :integration_1.

I've tried to use:

```
instance_a.connection_handler.connection_pools
```

And it lists all the connections. But how can I now witch database was instance_a loaded from?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: AFAIK instances have no memory of which connection they were retrieved from

Comment: If you are right, then when I call .save in the instance ActiveRecord could update the values in an arbitrary database? That sounds risky!

Comment: I believe so yes - if you are switching db connections around a lot that would be a hazard

Comment: Ok! Thanks so much then! I might add some constructor for each instance to save in an attr_accessor the connection. Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using mysql you probably can use:

`Timetable.connection.execute("select database()").first.first`

The other databases might have a query to get the current db too.